# Hazard model with time varying covariates

Tags: survival, time-varying-covariate

I am trying to build a discrete time event model. The event occurs once in 20 years period of time. Most of the example i saw use only covariates which are same over period of time. e.g. sex,race etc.

But i have observed values of covariates for different time periods.And there are around 10-15 covariates which are observed for 20 years.

I want to model all the time varying covariates for each year. e.g. in SAS the option is like:
 model event=var1 var2 var3 number_of_years

Here they have var1 var2 as race, sex etc, which are constant over period of time(time independent).
But i have like different var1 values observed for number of years.
So for second entity, its again different for number of years.

The event occurs once for given number of years in 1/0 form

I am using SAS, but can use R as well if that helps.

Please let me know, if you have any questions.

To clarify further:

Please refer to:
http://ccsr.ac.uk/qmss/summer/Paris09/documents/SingerWillet.pdf

in the last you can see logistic regression code.

I want to know how to include predictors like cash value along with dummy variables D01-D12
which are varying for 12 time periods.

Comment: *Please let me know if you have any questions* -- you need to have questions first. You didn't post any.

Comment: The problem if you figure from text is, that most of the examples that i came across have covariates which are constant for the entire time period. But in my situation i have covariates which are observed for all years. I want to capture them in my model, to find the event probability happening/not happening

Comment: Your question still doesn't contain a question. Even in your response in comments, you still only made statements. If possible, can you express what you want in the form of a question, and edit your question to contain it?

Comment: does that help?

Comment: I've read and reread your post but I am still not sure what your question really is.

Comment: maybe let somebody take on it

Comment: @user49305 A question usually ends with this piece of punctuation: '?'. I think I share Glen's perspective in the first, third and fifth comments. Can you simply edit your post to include (grammatically correct) sentences ending in a question mark? For what it's worth I am *very* familiar with discrete hazard models, and time varying covariates, and would be delighted to help answer your questions: *if you have any*.

Comment: Also: why is this tagged [cox-model]? Discrete-time event history models are not Cox models: they are two separate kinds of event history analysis. Can you clarify which one you are concerned with?